# Board to board connection

Tags: connector, cables

I have 2 boards that are normally stacked on top of each other using 2 x 7 pins 1mm pitch connectors. I'd like to separate them by a foot or so. But I can't find an extension for that pitch. What would be the alternative possibilities?
  [image]

PS: this is not meant to be a product recommendation question but a quest for a solution to an actual problem.

Comment: Hope for a wire-to-board male and female connector in the same series.

Comment: Ribbon cables and metal threaded rods.

Comment: It's likely that there's no such connector for a cable; this looks very much engineered for direct board-to-board connections. Anyway, product recommendation questions...

Comment: By the way, your [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/481763/14-pin-2x7-1-mm-pitch-male-female-extension) was already closed as such.

Comment: When skilled enough and having the right tools: desolder both connectors and wire them